# Returning Row to a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply, mapply

I'm trying to create a matrix of whether or not a date falls in the range created by my two columns, Data$StartDate and Data$EndDate. To this end, I've created the below function

```
DatesChecked <- as.character(seq(as.Date("2012-06-30"), as.Date("2017-12-09"), by = "day"))

CheckOpen <- function(x, row, column){
  if (Data$StartDate[row] > as.Date(column)) {
    return(0)
  } else {
    if (is.na(Data$EndDate[row])) {
      return(1)
  } else {
    ifelse(Data$EndDate > as.Date(column), return(1), return(0))
  }
  }
}

Data[,DatesChecked] <- mapply(CheckOpen, Data[,DatesChecked])
```

However I'm not sure how to pass row index as an argument to my function. I've put "row" in as a filler.

Ultimately though, I strongly suspect that I've taken completely the wrong approach. What I'm going to do next is take the sum of each column and put them back as a new column in "DatesChecked" and this seems like an overly complicated method (ie I'm counting how many rows each date falls within the range of).

Example Data:

```
      StartDate       EndDate
         <dttm>        <dttm>
1    2012-10-16    2014-02-19
2    2012-10-17    2013-04-16
3    2012-11-05    2013-04-22
4    2012-11-14    2013-05-01
5    2013-03-20    2013-08-29
6    2013-04-07    2013-09-09
```

In the column with title "2014-01-01" the results would be `c(1,0,0,0,0,0)` as the first row is the only one where it falls in the range.

Comment: If you could provide a small amount of example data, perhaps including a column with your expected outcome, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Updated, hope it helps

Comment: Were you hoping to get the full data matrix? Or just the sum of dates that falls between the intervals.

Comment: Just the sum. I would compress the matrix into sums.

Comment: Ah... okay. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a rather simple and plain solution.

```
DatesChecked <- seq(as.Date("2012-06-30"), as.Date("2017-12-09"), by = "day")

# summing TRUEs is like summing ones
cbind.data.frame(
  DatesChecked,
  sapply(DatesChecked, function(x) {
    sum(x > Data$StartDate & x < Data$EndDate)
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. First, write a function that checks if a specific date `x` is between two other dates `d1` and `d2`.

```
check <- function(x, d1, d2) ifelse(x >= d1 & x <= d2, 1, 0)
```

Then load up the tidyverse, and loop through all your checked dates with `purrr::map`, set the names to be the dates, then bind all the columns toghether.

```
library(tidyverse)
df_checked <- map(DatesChecked, ~check(., d$StartDate, d$EndDate)) %>% 
  set_names(DatesChecked) %>% 
  bind_cols()

# Show first five columns
df_checked[ ,1:5]

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  `2012-06-30` `2012-07-01` `2012-07-02` `2012-07-03` `2012-07-04`
         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1            0            0            0            0            0
2            0            0            0            0            0
3            0            0            0            0            0
4            0            0            0            0            0
5            0            0            0            0            0
6            0            0            0            0            0

# Show specific column mentioned in question
df_checked["2014-01-01"]

# A tibble: 6 x 1
  `2014-01-01`
         <dbl>
1         1.00
2         0   
3         0   
4         0   
5         0   
6         0
```